# Интеграция HWIOAuthBundle и FOSUserBundle - 302 ошибка и редирект

Tags: facebook, symfony, fosuserbundle

Доброго времени суток. Проблема в следующем:
Сделал по оф. мануалу интеграцию HWIOAuthBundle и FOSUserBundle. Стал проверять: перехожу по маршруту, который для этого зарегистрировал: /login/check-facebook, вылетает 302 ошибка и меня редиректит на маршрут /login/. Последний прописан в security.uml как failure_path. Ошибку бросает SecurityController, а в частности его action: loginAction.

Вот мои настройки:

routing.yml:

```
hwi_oauth_redirect:
resource: "@HWIOAuthBundle/Resources/config/routing/redirect.xml"
prefix:   /connect

hwi_oauth_connect:
    resource: "@HWIOAuthBundle/Resources/config/routing/connect.xml"
    prefix:   /connect

hwi_oauth_login:
    resource: "@HWIOAuthBundle/Resources/config/routing/login.xml"
    prefix:   /login

facebook_login:
    path: /login/check-facebook
```

security.yml:

```
security:
    encoders:
        FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserInterface: bcrypt

    role_hierarchy:
        ROLE_ADMIN:       ROLE_USER
        ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: ROLE_ADMIN

    providers:
        fos_userbundle:
            id: fos_user.user_provider.username

    firewalls:

        dev:
            pattern:  ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false

        connect:
            pattern:  ^/connect
            anonymous: ~

        secured_area:
            anonymous: ~
            oauth:
                resource_owners:
                    facebook:           "/login/check-facebook"
                login_path:        /login
                use_forward:       false
                failure_path:      /login

                oauth_user_provider:
                    service: my.oauth_aware.user_provider.service



    access_control:
        - { path: ^/login, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
```

services.yml:

```
services:
    my.oauth_aware.user_provider.service:
        class: HWI\Bundle\OAuthBundle\Security\Core\User\FOSUBUserProvider
        arguments:
            - '@fos_user.user_manager'
            - ['pass properties as array']

    my.custom.user_provider:
            class:        AppBundle\Service\FOSUBUserProvider
            arguments: ['@fos_user.user_manager', { facebook: facebook_id }]
```

config.yml:

```
hwi_oauth:
    connect:
        account_connector: my.custom.user_provider
    # list of names of the firewalls in which this bundle is active, this setting MUST be set
    firewall_names: [secured_area]
    # name of security firewall configured to work with HWIOAuthBundle
    fosub:
        username_iterations: 30
        properties:
            facebook:    facebook_id
    resource_owners:
        facebook:
            type:                facebook
            client_id:           xxx
            client_secret:       xxx
            scope:                "email"
```

И в src\AppBundle\Service забросил файл FOSUBUserProvider.php:

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Service;

use HWI\Bundle\OAuthBundle\OAuth\Response\UserResponseInterface;
use HWI\Bundle\OAuthBundle\Security\Core\User\FOSUBUserProvider as BaseFOSUBProvider;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;

class FOSUBUserProvider extends BaseFOSUBProvider
{
    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    public function connect(UserInterface $user, UserResponseInterface $response)
    {
        // get property from provider configuration by provider name
        // , it will return `facebook_id` in that case (see service definition below)
        $property = $this->getProperty($response);
        $username = $response->getUsername(); // get the unique user identifier

        //we "disconnect" previously connected users
        $existingUser = $this->userManager->findUserBy(array($property => $username));
        if (null !== $existingUser) {
            // set current user id and token to null for disconnect
            // ...

            $this->userManager->updateUser($existingUser);
        }
        // we connect current user, set current user id and token
        // ...
        $this->userManager->updateUser($user);
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function loadUserByOAuthUserResponse(UserResponseInterface $response)
    {
        $userEmail = $response->getEmail();
        $user = $this->userManager->findUserByEmail($userEmail);

        // if null just create new user and set it properties
        if (null === $user) {
            $username = $response->getRealName();
            $user = new User();
            $user->setUsername($username);

            // ... save user to database

            return $user;
        }
        // else update access token of existing user
        $serviceName = $response->getResourceOwner()->getName();
        $setter = 'set' . ucfirst($serviceName) . 'AccessToken';
        $user->$setter($response->getAccessToken());//update access token

        return $user;
    }
}
```

В чём может быть проблема?

Comment: У меня сложилось впечатление, что в документации HWIOAuthBundle одна половина написана для ситуации без FOSUserBundle, а вторая - с FOSUserBundle. И поэтому при использовании двух этих частей не получается с первого раза всё запустить.

У меня hwioauth и fosub заработали только после того, как я начал использовать пути /login для fosub, а /oauth для hwioauth

Comment: Добавьте в вопрос все настройки касающиеся fosub. Наверняка на пересечении настроек двух бандлов и есть ошибка

Answer (score 0):

Тоже промучился не один час с похожей проблемой. Решил тем что добавил в

```
access_control:
    - { path: ^/login$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/register, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/resetting, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/connect, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
```

последнюю строчку. Ведь получалось что после ответа от Facebook наш hwi_oauth должен вызывать `hwi_oauth_service_redirect` (если делать по документации), а его access_control рубил и редиректил на /login.